# Spring JPA - Repository Query is returning 0 rows

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have this repository class:

```
public interface ShiftRepository extends CrudRepository<Shift, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT s FROM Shift s")
    public List<Shift> getAllShifts();
}
```

All I want it to do is grab all shifts.

The Service calling it is just doing this:

```
 public List<Shift> getAllShifts() {
    return shiftRepository.getAllShifts();
 }
```

And the Controller is just doing this:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Shift>> getAllShifts() {
    List<Shift> shifts;
    try {
      shifts = shiftService.getAllShifts();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(new ArrayList<>());
    }

if (shifts != null) {
  System.out.println(shifts.size());
  return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(shifts);
} else {
  return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

}

On the frontend I am getting this response.
[Empty array of shifts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL315.png)

[succesful 200 response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdAdp.png)

So I don't know what the issue is, I just want all the records. Using Spring boot and Heroku Postgres

application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate.default_schema: dev_env
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  datasource:
    hikari:
      schema: dev_env
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    type: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems like in that Query annotation. You have to define value tag before your query. As:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT s FROM Shift s")
```

Comment: answer was provided, it was my mistake. I did try this though. For future reference, explicitly stating or omitting the value tag makes no difference in this case

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting time. It's late was very enthralled in Spring boot and React debugging my application. Did not realize I had not populated database with test data XD